# MySQL - Calculating profit from joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, inner-join

So I have two tables,

- one has the product margin before tax, and
- other table has the individuals products tax % (unfortunately in whole number format).

The code I'm using works, but some products are not taxed, and therefore have 0.

I'm trying to figure out how calculate their profit with the same formula I'm using.

```
SELECT o.product_id,
       (((o.total_margin/1000)-(p.tax/100)*o.total_margin/1000)/1000) AS Profit
FROM merproduct_offers o
JOIN merchant_products p ON o.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.tax > '1'
```

Linked below are screenshots of the two tables I'm using. Thanks again!

[image: select-statement]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: When pinned down, this is likely a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.  Reflect your research. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT 
    o.product_id, 
    (((o.total_margin/1000)-(COALESCE(p.tax, 0)/100)*o.total_margin/1000)/1000) AS Profit
FROM merproduct_offers o
LEFT JOIN merchant_products p
    ON o.product_id = p.product_id AND p.tax > 1
```

It is likely that the computation can be simplified, but it is hard to tell without an explanation of its purpose. *Maybe* something like this?

```
(o.total_margin / 1000 - COALESCE(p.tax, 0) * o.total_margin / 100000) / 1000 AS Profit
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I might have expressed myself incorrectly, the computation doesn't need to be simplified. In this case, Some products have no values in the total_margin column, which is why running the query above returns a 0 value for profit right?

Comment: @GabrielTome: the `inner join` filters out products that have no tax information, while the `left join` dodes not (it returns a `null` value for `p.tax`, which we turn to `0` using `coalesce()`). Don't worry about the computation simplification part: that was just me trying to further make things more readable...

Comment: Thank you very much! That may be the problem, with this other query I'm dealing with then. I appreciate your time and patience, due to being a new user, my upvote isn't registering but it's definitely upvoted :)